# How to set preference of a particular type in Android throughout the application?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application, I let users choose them Gender (Male, Female, Others).

And with regard to the Gender, I show them the Avatar icon at many screens in the application.

is there any way to do this? I don't want if-else everywhere I show the Avatar icon.

I am sharing the gender in the SharedPreferences though.

Any configs file or settings? I am not able to even search the query on Google about this particular question.

Comment: Why not a utils method? That would have all the if-else based on the shared pref and just return the avatar reference, probably a drawable id

Comment: Can you please share the code where you set the avatar?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create one class and can use it anywhere.

**AppUtils.java**

```
public class AppUtils {
    public static int getAvtarFromGender(Context context) {
        if (isMale(context)) {
            return R.drawable.male_icon;
        } else {
            return R.drawable.female_icon;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isMale(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedpreferences.getBoolean("key_for_gender_preff", false);
    }

    public void savePreffIsMale(Context context, boolean isMale) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key_for_gender_preff, isUserLoggedIn);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

**Use of AppUtils class:**

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.m_imageview);
imageView.setImageResource(AppUtils.getAvtarFromGender(mContext));
```